# Configuring Spring Boot's embedded tomcat container with basic auth

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot 1.5.7, ***without*** Spring Security. My objective is to experiment with the embedded tomcat container and enable basic authn.

Here is what I have:

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
    final TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
    tomcat.addContextCustomizers(ctx -> {
        String AUTH_ROLE = "admin";
        LoginConfig config = new LoginConfig();
        config.setAuthMethod("BASIC");
        ctx.setLoginConfig(config);
        ctx.addSecurityRole(AUTH_ROLE);
        SecurityConstraint constraint = new SecurityConstraint();
        constraint.addAuthRole(AUTH_ROLE);
        SecurityCollection collection = new SecurityCollection();
        collection.addPattern("/*");
        constraint.addCollection(collection);
        ctx.addConstraint(constraint);
    });

    return tomcat;
}
```

This does not seem to have any effect. Is this sort of thing possible with Spring Boot programmatically, or could it only be done via the likes of web.xml?

PS: There are any number of posts on Stackoverflow detailing various solutions and alternatives that involve the Spring Security project. I should re-emphasize here that I would like to learn if there is a way to solve this without involving that library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration is good, but you need to add a Basic authenticator valve to the factory:

```
 final TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
    tomcat.addContextValves(new BasicAuthenticator());
    tomcat.addContextCustomizers(....
```

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you very much for your insight.

Comment: @b0c1 Just utilised the above tip to get my cert based authentication working in tomcat. 
Would love to know where I can find the above documented if you can recommend a place? It would be good to know why what I'm doing.. works!